# {blogdown} a fixed bib for every post

Tags: r, blogdown

Is it possible to change bib location for {blogdown} so I don't have to copy a .bib file for every post? I've tried something like

```
bibliography: [../../content/post/bib.bib]
```

with no success.

Here's my [repo](https://github.com/albersonmiranda/blog).

Comment: That should be okay. By "no success", what did you get when you inserted `@key` in your post? I looked at your repo but it seems you had changed the location of the bib file and the latest commit is no longer a reproducible example. It'll be great if you could point out the SHA1 hash of your repo that corresponds to the actual reproducible example.

Comment: It couldn't find the file. But I must've been mentally fatigued 'cause it worked normally right now :|

Comment: Okay. That's good to know. It seems we can close this question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to put my .bib file in `blog/content/post/` folder, which means going back one level from post's default working directory (e.g., `blog/content/post/some post/index.Rmd`). So the bibliography location should be `[../bib.bib]`.